# Transaction with many query

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, transactions

I have a Mysql class to make query like this.

```
protected MySqlConnection _connection = null;
public bool Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            this._connection = new MySqlConnection(this._connectionString);
            this._connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
            return false;
        }
    }

public MySQLParameters Prepare(MySqlCommand command)
    {
        try
        {
            command.Connection = this._connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            return new MySQLParameters(command);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
        }
    }

public void Query(MySqlCommand command)
    {
        try
        {
            command.Connection = this._connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
        }
    }
public DataSet QueryResult(MySqlCommand command)
    {

        try
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            command.Connection = this._connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            return dataSet;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to use this with Transaction

But I don't know where to add the `transaction commit` and `rollback`

Because now I'm use my class like this.

```
RemoteMySQL mySql = new RemoteMySQL();
mySql.Connect();
string sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` SET ";
sql += "`name` = @name, ";
sql += "`lastname` = @lastname;";
MySQLParameters parameters = mySql.Prepare(sql);
parameters["name"] = name;
parameters["lastname"] = lastname;
mySql.Query(parameters.GetCommand());

sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
ds = mySql.QueryResult(sql);
customerId = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

sql = "INSERT INTO `table2` SET ";
sql += "`customer_id` = @customer_id, ";
sql += "`item` = @item, ";
sql += "`detail` = @detail;";
parameters = mySql.Prepare(sql);
parameters["customer_id"] = customerId;
parameters["item"] = item;
parameters["detail"] = detail;
mySql.Query(parameters.GetCommand());

// I want to commit here
// If can't insert to table2 will rollback table1 too.
```

I have a look at http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/ (on trasaction)

But still don't know how to use with my code (where to put commit and rollback)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be used the same way as a SQLConnection

```
public void Query(MySqlCommand command)
    {
        var transaction = this._connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
        try
        {
            command.Connection = this._connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I call `mySql.Query()` 2 times. Is it will rollback my first `table1` if `table2` got exception ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- it will do a rollback or commit, depending on whether or not it hits an exception, after each `mySql.Query()` call.

Comment: It not work,  I think because I call `mySql.Query()` 2 times. First time `table1` is commit already so when `table2` it won't rollback anymore. this is error message `System.InvalidOperationException: Transaction has already been committed or is not pending
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Commit()`

Comment: Then why not combine the 2 queries into one transaction and call Query() once?

Comment: I have got 6 queries that use `mySql.Query()` for only execute and `mySql.QueryResult()`  for execute and return Data. Any idea for how can I combine them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got solution for this, But don't know this is the right thing to do?

I create new method for transaction thing like `@ragerory` told me.

```
public void TransactionQuery(ArrayList list)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (MySqlCommand command in list)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
                command.Connection = this._connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Transaction = this._transaction;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            this._transaction.Commit(); 
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            this._transaction.Rollback();
            throw new MySQLException(ex.Message, ex.Number);
        }
    }
```

and I use like this.

```
RemoteMySQL mySql = new RemoteMySQL();
mySql.Connect();
string sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` SET ";
sql += "`name` = @name, ";
sql += "`lastname` = @lastname;";
MySQLParameters parameters = mySql.Prepare(sql);
parameters["name"] = name;
parameters["lastname"] = lastname;
//mySql.Query(parameters.GetCommand()); not use this.
list.Add(parameters.GetCommand());

sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
ds = mySql.QueryResult(sql);
customerId = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

sql = "INSERT INTO `table2` SET ";
sql += "`customer_id` = @customer_id, ";
sql += "`item` = @item, ";
sql += "`detail` = @detail;";
parameters = mySql.Prepare(sql);
parameters["customer_id"] = customerId;
parameters["item"] = item;
parameters["detail"] = detail;
//mySql.Query(parameters.GetCommand()); not use this.
list.Add(parameters.GetCommand());
// And call this method last line.
mySql.TransactionQuery(list);
```

It work now. But Question is. Is this OK to do like this? (Right thing?)

Thank you.

Comment: Got problem with `mySql.QueryResult()` that use to return dataset from query `sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
                    ds = mySql.QueryResult(sql);` it can not select last insert id from table because the query is execute on the bottom line ToT